# How to verify the presence of a string in a constant list of strings

Tags: c#, string, list, collections

This should be easy, but I don't find the correct syntax: I would like to know if my name is present in a contant list of strings.

These are my attempts:

```
// first idea
if (Destination.Name in {"MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG"})

// after some searching
if IndexOf(new string[] { "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG" }, Destination.Name)
```

... but none of them seems to work.

What's the easiest way to get this done in C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (new string[] {"MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG"}.Contains(Destination.Name)) {...}`

Comment: if your string is an element in a list of strings (exact match) or if it is a substring in that list of strings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, you are looking for `Destination.Name` in `"MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG"` (i.e. if `Destination.Name` is `MA` or `MB` etc.):

```
if (new string[] { "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG" }.Contains(Destination.Name)) 
{
  ...
}
```

Same for `IndexOf`: we check if `Destination.Name` index within the array is not negative:

```
// Either use List, or ugly
// if (Array.IndexOf(new string[] {...}, Destination.Name)) {...}
if (new List<string> { "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG" }
      .IndexOf(Destination.Name) >= 0) 
{
  ...
}
```

Finally, in *general case* you can *query* array with a help of *Linq*.
It's an *overshoot* here, but if you have a *non-trivial condition*, lambda
function (here it is `item => item == Destination.Name`) could be very flexible.

```
using System.Linq;

...

// If the array has any item which is equal to Destination.Name 
if (new string[] { "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG" }
      .Any(item => item == Destination.Name))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain why you should (or should not) use each of these options.

Comment: Your second approach with IndexOf I dont think is valid since there's no overload for method 'IndexOf that takes 1 argument. Maybe you thought of Array.IndexOf?

Comment: @Izanagi: Thank you! You are quite right - either `List<string>` or ugly `Array.IndexOf(...)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Thanks for your quick reply. I went for the first solution (as the one in your first comment), as it resembles the closest of what I was looking for.